# LessCss: nesting groups of selectors

Tags: css-selectors, less, twitter-bootstrap-3, nested, lessphp

Say in my `main.less` file which gets compiled into `main.css`, I have the following:

```
.section1 {
    .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1,
    .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2,
    .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3,
    .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4,
    .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5,
    .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, 
    .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7,
    .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8,
    .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9,
    .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10,
    .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11,
    .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12
    {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
}
.section2 {
    .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1,
    .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2,
    .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3,
    .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4,
    .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5,
    .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, 
    .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7,
    .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8,
    .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9,
    .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10,
    .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11,
    .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12
    {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```

Clearly this is already becoming unwieldy, excessively cluttering my main.less file and adding duplication of sorts which could cause multiple unnecessary changes.

How can I improve this? Is there a way I could for example do something like this:

```
.allCellTypes 
{
    .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1,
    .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2,
    .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3,
    .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4,
    .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5,
    .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, 
    .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7,
    .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8,
    .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9,
    .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10,
    .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11,
    .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12
}
.section1 .allCellTypes 
{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.section2 .allCellTypes 
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Thanks

Edit 1: As per @Alessandro Minoccheri's suggestion, I compiled but the resulting css was as follows:

```
.section1 .allCellTypes 
{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.section2 .allCellTypes 
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Any mention of the classes that would be covered by `.allCellTypes` are completely omitted. Perhaps there are two reasons for this?

1. The definitions for the classes which would be grouped into `.allCellTypes` are defined elsewhere (within compiled bootstrap files).
2. I compile the `.less` files using lessphp, perhaps it has a bug?

Edit 2: I placed the following code in the demo window on the [lessphp page](http://leafo.net/lessphp/)...

```
.cell1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.cell2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.cell3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.allCellTypesClass {
  .cell1;
  .cell2;
  .cell3;
}
.section1 {
  .allCellTypes {
    .allCellTypesClass;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

and I got the following result:

```
.cell1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.cell2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.cell3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.allCellTypesClass {
  background-color: red;
  background-color: green;
  background-color: blue;
}
.section1 .allCellTypes {
  background-color: red;
  background-color: green;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

So I'm afraid your answer, @Alessandro Minoccheri, is not doing what I wanted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gist of what I do is as follows:

My Mixin:

```
.red-border () {
   border:@value @value @value;
}
```

Applying:

```
.section-2 [class*="col-"] {
  .red-border;
}
```

If you don't want to affect nested columns, then:

```
.section-2 > [class*="col-"] {
  .red-border;
}
```

If you only want a certain column breakpoint:

```
.section-2 > [class*="col-sm-"] {
  .red-border;
}
```

If you don't want to affect forms (haven't tested this but should work fine).

```
.section-2 > [class*="col-"]:not(form) {
  .red-border;
}
```

Comment: I use something like this here to fix the forms a lot with min classes: http://jsbin.com/uSoruFUK/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, you can get it in LESS like this:

```
.section1 {
    .allCells; .allCellsProperties() {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
}

.section2 {
    .allCells; .allCellsProperties() {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}

.allCells() {.col- {&xs-, &sm-, &md-, &lg- {
    &1, &2, &3, &4, &5, &6, &7, &8, &9, &10, &11, &12 {
        .allCellsProperties();
    }
}}}
```

But indeed, the attribute-selector-based solution suggested by @cab is more clean and less bloating.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class `.allCellTypes`  and add all class that you want that inherited.After you can call this class and add other property
you can write this:

```
.allCellTypesClass 
    {
    .col-xs-1; 
    .col-sm-1; 
    .col-md-1;
    .col-lg-1;
    .col-xs-2; 
    .col-sm-2; 
    .col-md-2;
    .col-lg-2;
    .col-xs-3; 
    .col-sm-3; 
    .col-md-3;
    .col-lg-3;
    .col-xs-4; 
    .col-sm-4; 
    .col-md-4; 
    .col-lg-4;
    .col-xs-5; 
    .col-sm-5; 
    .col-md-5; 
    .col-lg-5;
    .col-xs-6; 
    .col-sm-6; 
    .col-md-6; 
    .col-lg-6; 
    .col-xs-7; 
    .col-sm-7; 
    .col-md-7; 
    .col-lg-7;
    .col-xs-8; 
    .col-sm-8; 
    .col-md-8; 
    .col-lg-8;
    .col-xs-9; 
    .col-sm-9; 
    .col-md-9; 
    .col-lg-9;
    .col-xs-10; 
    .col-sm-10; 
    .col-md-10;
    .col-lg-10;
    .col-xs-11; 
    .col-sm-11; 
    .col-md-11; 
    .col-lg-11;
    .col-xs-12; 
    .col-sm-12; 
    .col-md-12; 
    .col-lg-12;
}

.section1
{
  .allCellTypes 
    {
       .allCellTypesClass;
       border: 1px solid green;
    }    
}
.section2 
{
    .allCellTypes 
    {
       .allCellTypesClass ;
       border: 1px solid red;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Cool, +1. Have some link with documentation, like mozilla or w3c? I've searched but not found. Thanks!

Comment: is the property of less where you can concatenate more than a class  see this lesscss.org @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was pure css, thanks for clarifying me. +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unfortunately it has not worked, I have clarified in my answer what I am doing to get the incorrect result, perhaps you could explain how I could reproduce your success?

Comment: edit answer try now please... I think isn't a bug of lessphp because I have work with that library and this functionality works fine for me. be sure that the other file is called before this file to include that class @Jodes

Comment: Thank you, I have tried again but the css output was no different

Comment: ok be sure that the other file with the class to include is called before your declaration of css and check into your net console if that file is called. @Jodes